# shutdown VM and Fatal Exception in Android

Tags: java, android

I tried bt every time i see a log cat Having message of **Fatal Exception and shutdown VM** through there are some solution regarding this error i cant find it please help me to out of it i am new in android so might be there is a small mistake by me so give me solution

Below is my code

main.java

```
package com.login.demo;
import impl.dao.InspectionVO;
import impl.dao.Inspection_damages;
import impl.dbOperation.Operation;
import impl.internetcheck.CkeckNetConnection;
import impl.urlConnection.CommonUtill;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class main extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    EditText unm, pwd;
    String webResponse1 = "NA";
    String uname, password;
    Operation op = new Operation(this);
    SharedPreferences pref;
    static String jsonstr;
    public static String msg = "nothing";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        unm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button lgn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        op.getContainerid();


        //****Check for Connection at First time********
        lgn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        uname = unm.getText().toString().trim();
        password=  pwd.getText().toString().trim();

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1)
        {
            String status = CkeckNetConnection.getConnectivityStatusString(main.this);
            if (status.equals("Mobile"))
            {
                MyAsynTask obj = new MyAsynTask();
                //Testing?param1=admin&param2=admin
                String login = "firstLogin?param1=" + uname + "&param2=" + password;

                //String login = "Testing?param1="+uname+"&param2="+password;
                //  String SubURL ="insertInsp?param1="+str1;
                Log.i("check 1", "Info 1");
                try
                {
                    msg = "Login..";
                    obj.execute(login).get();
                    Log.i("Login object", "Text set : " + jsonstr);
                    if (jsonstr.equals("true"))
                    {
                        Log.i("ketan", "Inside condition");
                        String inspid = op.getContainerid();
                        Log.i("id", inspid);
                        int ids=Integer.parseInt(inspid);
                        int id=1;
                        if(ids>0)
                        {
                            //Log.i("Test1","Here");
                            while(id<=ids)
                            {
                                InspectionVO insp=op.getInspection(id);
                                Gson gson=new Gson();
                                //String jsonStr=gson.toJson(insp);

                                StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
                                tmp.append(gson.toJson(insp));
                                Log.i("Stringssss", tmp.toString());



                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                sb.append("insertInsp?param1="+java.net.URLEncoder.encode(tmp.toString()));

                                MyAsynTask inspection=new MyAsynTask();
                                inspection.execute(sb.toString()).get();


                                ArrayList<Inspection_damages> ar=op.getImages(id);
                                for(Integer k=0;k<ar.size();k++)
                                {
                                    ar.get(k).setInsp_id(jsonstr);
                                    StringBuilder tmp1 = new StringBuilder();
                                    tmp1.append(gson.toJson(ar.get(k)));
                                    Log.i("Stringssss", ar.get(k).getD_code());
                                    Log.i("Stringssss", tmp1.toString());

                                    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                                    sb1.append("insertInspDamage?param1="+java.net.URLEncoder.encode(tmp1.toString()));
                                    Log.i("left", sb1.toString());
                                    MyAsynTask obj1=new MyAsynTask();
                                    obj1.execute(sb1.toString()).get();

                                }

                                id++;


                            }

                        }
                        /*    msg="recieving data..";
                        String uid = op.getusersid();
                        Log.i("Response","check it"+uid);
                        MyAsynTask user = new MyAsynTask();
                        String users = "getUsers?param1="+uid;
                        user.execute(users).get();
                        Log.i("Response", jsonstr);
                        Gson gson = new Gson();

                        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<UserVO>>() {}.getType();
                        ArrayList<UserVO> ar = gson.fromJson(jsonstr,type);
                        if(!(ar==null))
                        {
                            op.InsertUsers(ar);
                        }
                        /*    MyAsynTask cont=new MyAsynTask();
                        String conts="getCT?";
                        cont.execute(conts).get();
                        Log.i("Response", jsonstr);


                        Type types = new TypeToken<ArrayList<InspectionVO>>() {}.getType();
                        ArrayList<InspectionVO> cnar= gson.fromJson(jsonstr,types);
                        op.InsertCT(cnar);*/

                        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),mainbutton.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully login",10).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.i("Login status", "fail");
                        Toast.makeText(main.this, "Wrong username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        unm.setText("");
                        pwd.setText("");
                    }

                    /*String users="getUsers?";
                    obj.execute(users).get();
                    Log.i("Response", jsonstr);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();

                    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<UserVO>>() {}.getType();
                    ArrayList<UserVO> ar = gson.fromJson(jsonstr,type);
                    */ 
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if(status.equals("Not"))
            {
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),mainbutton.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully login",10).show();
                /*    Toast.makeText(main.this, "No Net Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                unm.setText("");
                pwd.setText("");*/
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(main.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //set message of the dialog
            Asycdialog.setMessage(msg);
            //show dialog
            Asycdialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            //String webResponse= CommonUtill.getOutputFromUrl(CommonUtill.URL+"checkLogin?param1=admin&param2=admin");
            jsonstr=CommonUtill.getOutputFromUrl(CommonUtill.URL+params[0]);


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }





        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            //hide the dialog
            Asycdialog.dismiss();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
07-16 02:08:18.065: D/AndroidRuntime(2160): Shutting down VM
07-16 02:08:18.065: W/dalvikvm(2160): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3eae648)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:159)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at com.login.demo.main.onClick(main.java:87)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 02:08:29.686: I/Process(2160): Sending signal. PID: 2160 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Try to control second parameters in log.i() calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause

This exception is coming because you are **passing a null value to Log** i.e you are trying to log an uninitialized reference of an object or an instance that now points to null, as indicated in the following line of the logcat

> 07-16 02:08:18.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2160): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

### Solution

- Always use null check before logging

  > if (insipid != null)
  >       Log.i("id", inspid);
- Append "" to the value being logged, this will ensure that the final value for logging is never null. *However this is bad approach, null objects should ideally be checked and logged as shown above.*

  > Log.i("id", "" + inspid);

### Possible locations in code

The following two code blocks looks like ideal candidates for the exception.

**Location 1:**

```
Log.i("id", inspid); <<--inspid may be null
```

**Location 2:**

```
ar.get(k).setInsp_id(jsonstr);
StringBuilder tmp1 = new StringBuilder();
tmp1.append(gson.toJson(ar.get(k)));
Log.i("Stringssss", ar.get(k).getD_code()); <<--ar.get(k).getD_code() may be null
Log.i("Stringssss", tmp1.toString()); <<--tmp1 may be null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing all your Logs like

```
 Log.i("Stringssss", tmp.toString());
```

with

```
 Log.i("Stringssss","" +tmp.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a null object into Log.i somewhere into your method onClick.
You can protect your objects logs by calling String.valueOf which is null safe and returns `"null"`
Use

```
Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(myObject));
```

or

```
Log.i(TAG, "MyObject="+myObject);
```

instead of

```
Log.i(TAG, myObject);
```

if you don't want to bother with testing for the nulliness of your objects.